# Lack of the article with 'free time'

Tags: grammar, articles

If we use the indefinite article 'a' with 'good time' because it means 'occasion' or 'period' ("I had a good time"), why don't we use 'a' with 'free time' ("I did not have free time")?

Comment: Dictionaries cannot cover every fixed expression (though OED may get close), never mind strong and weak collocations and especially non-idiomatic candidate usages. Note that in 'We had quite a time', 'time' (if considered outside the fixed expression) is non-count because 'we had quite 2 times' or equivalent is not available. 'Good times were here again' shows a plural non-count usage ('8 good times were here' being unacceptable). And while 'free period' is a fixed (count) expression, 'free time' is also fixed _but_ either non-count itself or containing a non-count usage of 'time'.

Comment: In other words: Never mind "good"; as soon as you add the article ("I had a time"), you've entered a specific idiomatic usage.

Answer (score 1):

Article usage and non-usage in English is so subject to idiomatic variation that I hesitate to generalize. However it seems to me that it might be helpful to emphasize the difference between the countable and uncountable usage of *time* in the two examples, and the different roles of the modifying adjectives in each case.

*Time* used in a *countable sense*, denotes a *fixed period or occasion*, as the original poster notes. One would expect a general instance to take the indefinite article and a particular instance the definite article, e.g.

> “**A time** to reap, a time to sow.”
>
> “**The last time** I saw Paris.”

Each of these, as one would expect, can be modified by an appropriate adjective:

> “It was **a great time** to be alive.”
>
> “This is **the best time** to hunt for snarks.”

*Time* used in the *uncountable sense* generally does not allow of similar adjectival qualification in non-colloquial speech in the singular. We could say

> “Enjoy your time here”

but *not*

> “Enjoy your good time here”

So what about “free time”? In my view the modifying “adjective” is being used to create a more specific, but still uncountable, variant of time.

A similar example is “spare time”, and the difference from “good time” can be seen clearly in cases in which the adjective has merged with the noun — “playtime”, “springtime”, “swingtime”.

Still uncountable:

> “**In springtime**, the only pretty ring time,”

Oh! But what about “ring time”? Here *ring* is just a second adjective after *pretty* with a countable usage of time. (Not sure what ring time is actually, but if Shakespeare wrote it, it must be all right.)

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the good answer by David, the question is whether "time" is countable or not.  In the case that "time" means what the French call "temps", it is an abstract phenomenon, or substance, and is non-count, like words like "energy", "training", etc, and will not take an article, like all such words if you are talking about it in a general, unrestricted way.  In the case that "time" means what the French call "fois", it is countable, and will take an article, unless that is replaced by another determiner, (like "five" etc.) David basically said this, with the words "occasion" and "concept", but I thought the term "countable" would help someone who seems to be an ESL student.

Comment: "A good time," the OP's example, does not map to "fois" at all.  Word Reference suggests "bon moment" but this doesn't seem quite the same to me.